# Trying to use sessionStorage in javascript

Tags: javascript, session-storage

I'm trying to show a popup window only once per session. In order to achieve that I'm using sessionStorage function. however, the popup is showing up whenever I reload the web page. Can you please let me know where I'm making the mistake.

```
dialogue = new IMu.App.Dialogue();
dialogue.setHtmlMessage(IMu.string('dialogue-heading'));
dialogue.show({ showDetails: true });

window.sessionStorage.setItem('message','true');
var is_dialogue = window.sessionStorage.getItem('message');
if (is_dialogue != 'true')
{
    dialogue.show();
}
```

Below is the show function

```
show: function(options, callback)
{
   if (typeof(options) == 'function')
   {
       callback = options;
       options = undefined;
   }
   var test = jQuery('body').children('div.imu-dialogue');
   jQuery('body').children('div.imu-dialogue').remove();
   var owner = self.owner = jQuery('body').child('div', 'imu-dialogue');

    var box = owner.child('div', 'box');

    var message = box.child('div', 'message');
    if (this.message)
    {
        var value = this.message.value;
        var method = this.message.type;
        message[method](value);
    }
            
    if (self.details)
    {
        var details = box.child('div', 'details');
        for (var i in self.details)
        {
             if (! self.details.hasOwnProperty(i))
             continue;

             var detail = details.child('div', 'detail');

             var value = self.details[i].value;
             var method = self.details[i].type || 'text';

             detail[method](value);
          }

           var show = box.child('div', 'show-details');
           if (! options || options.showDetails !== true)
           {
                show.text('Details');
                details.hide();
           }
           else
           {
                details.show();
                show.text('I agree');
           }

           show.on('click', function()
           {
                 self.owner.remove();
           });
}
```

Comment: What is it that you expect "session" to mean?

Comment: The popup should be shown only once in a session. Whenever the page is closed and opened again (a new session) the popup should be shown but it shouldn't be shown when the page is refreshed.

Comment: Yes. My question again: what is it that you think the word "session" is supposed to mean?

Comment: A particular time period where a user is active on a site and if a user is inactive for 30 minutes or more, any future activity is considered as a new session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got your logic backwards. You need to check if the `sessionStorage` item has been set **first**. If it has not been set, show the dialog and then set it.

```js
if (!sessionStorage.getItem('notified')) {
  let dialogue = new IMu.App.Dialogue();
  dialogue.setHtmlMessage(IMu.string('dialogue-heading'));
  dialogue.show({ showDetails: true });
  sessionStorage.setItem('notified', 'true');
}
```

There is no need to check the value of the stored property. Simply testing for it's existence is enough.

Answer (score 0):

Forget the `dialogue.show();`

If you try in a new tab of your browser the following code:

```
window.sessionStorage.setItem('message','true');
is_dialogue = window.sessionStorage.getItem('message');
is_dialogue != 'true' // false
```

refresh the page and run

```
is_dialogue = window.sessionStorage.getItem('message');
is_dialogue != 'true' // false
```

You may have something in your code whick clean session storage on mounted or on created ?